# How to make eye tracker for flat eyes that already applying lattice

Tags: animation, modifiers, rigging, lattice

Im new at blender and i stumble this problem on my simple character project where the character using lattice / flat eye, is there any way to make an eye tracker to animate the character because the one tutorial i found need me to not applying the lattice modifier while my character already applied it and i havent found a way to do this with lattice modifier already applied, or is there realy no other way ?

blend file : http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52053

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is well explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MfxTdq0V2I).

I don't think it is recommended to apply the *Lattice* modifier, and I think you should begin with a round sphere, not a flat sphere, otherwise it won't deform properly. So:

- First create your lattice around your eye sphere. Keep the lattice cubic. Give your eye a *Lattice* modifier with the Lattice as *Object*. Give your lattice a basis shape key and create a second shape key.

[image]

- Keep the lattice selected, go in *Edit* mode, select the second shape key, scale the lattice on the Y axis.

[image]

- Back in *Object* mode, select the second shape key and push the value to 1, the eye should deform. Then bring it back to 0 for the moment.

[image]

- Create a bone at the center of the eye, use the 3D cursor as *Pivot Point* to rotate it 90° so that it point forwards. Create a second bone that will be the target. Give the first bone a *Track To* constraint with this second bone as Target. Parent the eye to its bone, move the target, the eye should follow.

[image]
[image]

Comment: thankyou for answering my question again, yes i end up making the eye again and not applying the modifier and it looks like it work but i have problem cause the pupil look at the back(inside of face) instead of front whenever i use copy rotation (using youtube method) and when i use the bone method you explained the pupil facing upward. its like the rotation messed up or something

this is my updated file if you dont mind to take a look : http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52057

Comment: you must give your bone a BONE constraint (select it in Pose mode and select the BONE CONSTRAINTS tab), not an OBJECT constraint to the armature, plus keep both the 2 bones within the same armature, it will be much more convenient

Comment: thankyou work perfectly

Comment: also when you'll make a face, join these bones to the same armature, it will make things easier as well

Comment: yea i already joined the focus and eye bone , but should i join the left and right eye to one armature ? and is it okay to separate eye bone and body rig?

Comment: it's better to have only one armature, so for example make the head bone the parent of your eyes and target, etc

Comment: okay noted, thankyou really appreciate it :)