# How to make a fake eye highlight？

Tags: rigging

[image]

I am watching an animation tutorial from blender studio.
their new character has a fake eye highlight I am so interesting to make it.
Anyone can give me some ideas?

Comment: I guess it's just an image texture, you can create it with photoshop or krita

Comment: I know how to create but, how to rig this little image?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145445/how-to-make-eye-tracker-for-flat-eyes-that-already-applying-lattice

Comment: https://youtu.be/C7l3ojbeRZY?t=430  This is the reference video.

Comment: Rex is a Blender 3.0 rig that uses geometry nodes in the eye shader.  You need to look at rex.highlights to see how the highlight was done.

Comment: @moonboots The Sprite Fright characters are using a mix of geometry nodes and shaders to manage things like the eye highlight. That way they can move the highlight within the Iris by animation techniques that aren't described in the video which explains how to use the rig but not how it was built.

Comment: @garyyang you're probably going to have to look at the Sprite Fright rigging videos to figure out exactly what's going on.  I don't think many people outside of Blender Studio have had a chance to digest how they did things like that.

Comment: or you can try the UV Warp modifier, you'll just need to overlay 2 image textures: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181389/how-can-i-animate-a-2d-face-rig-on-any-3d-object